# #include <...> and INCLUDE variable

Tags: c++, include, include-path

When i include the file

```
#include "boost/random.hpp"
```

This random.hpp file is

```
#ifndef BOOST_RANDOM_HPP
#define BOOST_RANDOM_HPP

// generators
#include <boost/random/additive_combine.hpp>
#include <boost/random/discard_block.hpp>


#endif // BOOST_RANDOM_HPP
```

I cannot find boost/random/additive_combine.hpp or another headers. 
I've already modified INCLUDE variable.

INCLUDE has "C:\Users\Игорь\Downloads\boost_1_61_0\boost_1_61_0" the path with ..\boost\random\additive_combine.hpp

What's wrong ?

Comment: It sounds like your installation of Boost is faulty.

Comment: But i just want some hpp with classes. Theres no need to install  anything

Comment: @igor , you probably want to add boost root directory (I assume it's `C:\Users\Игорь\Downloads\boost_1_61_0\boost_1_61_0` for you) into you include path and simply `#include <boost/random.hpp>`. Make sure you are not moving/copying any header files from/into boost directory.

Comment: There's a need to have a working installation of the Boost headers.  If your compilations are failing because some headers are missing, then the installation of the set of headers is, apparently, faulty.  Or you're mis-specifying the command line options to find the headers.  Or whatever the real problem is.

Comment: I cannot find headers. It seems very strange to me.

Comment: C:\Users\Игорь\Downloads\boost_1_61_0\boost_1_61_0\boost\random Here are all headers i want , but     
    #include <boost/random/additive_combine.hpp> doesnt work

; cmd writes 
    "No such file or directory"

Comment: Don't you mean `#include <boost/random.hpp>`?

Comment: C:\Users\Игорь\Downloads\boost_1_61_0\boost_1_61_0. Here is the folder "boost". In the folder "boost" there are "random.hpp" and folder "random" with the other invicible headers. Their invicibility is the problem.